# How to group by month of a date using a function in a select statement

Tags: sql-server, function, group-by, subquery, case

I am having problems grouping by the month of a date when using a function. It was working before but the query was less complicated as I am now using a function that uses a rolling year from the current month. Here is my code.

```
SELECT
    CASE 
WHEN DATEDIFF(mm,dbo.fn_firstofmonth(getdate()), dbo.fn_firstofmonth(D.expected_date)) < 12
THEN DATEDIFF(mm,dbo.fn_firstofmonth(getdate()), dbo.fn_firstofmonth(D.expected_date)) + 1
ELSE 13 END AS [Expected Month],
    P.probability AS [Category], COUNT(O.id) AS [Customers]
FROM opportunity_probability P
INNER JOIN opportunity_detail D ON D.probability_id = P.id
INNER JOIN opportunities O ON D.opportunity_id = O.id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT opportunity_id
    FROM opportunity_detail
    GROUP BY opportunity_id
) T ON T.opportunity_id = O.customer_id
GROUP BY P.probability, MONTH(D.expected_date)
ORDER BY  P.probability, MONTH(D.expected_date)
```

It works if I have D.expected_date in the GROUP BY but I need to group on the MONTH of this date as it does not bring through the data correctly.

Comment: I would consider this query to be too long and complex to simply paste in a question and expect a meaningful answer without showing some sample input/output and possibly a table schema.

Comment: why r u getting MaxDate from your sub-query even not using it anywhere....

Comment: Thank you Zafar for pointing that out, I was using it for something else but have removed it now so have deleted MAX(date_added)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always remove the group by, then put your entire select into another select, and than group by the outer select:

```
select t.A, t.B from (select A, datepart(month, b) as B) t group by t.A, t.B
```

This way you can address your month field as if it where a normal field.

Example is far from complete, but should get you on your way.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go

Answer (score 2):

You can try to find month by this code:

`GROUP BY P.probability, DATEPART(month, D.expected_date)`

Comment: I get the following error Column 'opportunity_detail.expected_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: expected_date is in which table?

Comment: expected_date is from the opportunity_detail table which I have aliased as D

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT
to_char(D.expected_date, 'YYYY-MM'),
    CASE 
WHEN DATEDIFF(mm,dbo.fn_firstofmonth(getdate()), dbo.fn_firstofmonth(D.expected_date)) < 12
THEN DATEDIFF(mm,dbo.fn_firstofmonth(getdate()), dbo.fn_firstofmonth(D.expected_date)) + 1
ELSE 13 END AS [Expected Month],
    P.probability AS [Category], COUNT(O.id) AS [Customers]
FROM opportunity_probability P
INNER JOIN opportunity_detail D ON D.probability_id = P.id
INNER JOIN opportunities O ON D.opportunity_id = O.id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT opportunity_id
    FROM opportunity_detail
    GROUP BY opportunity_id
) T ON T.opportunity_id = O.customer_id
GROUP BY P.probability, to_char(D.expected_date, 'YYYY-MM')
ORDER BY  P.probability, to_char(D.expected_date, 'YYYY-MM')
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time but an error appears, Invalid column name 'exp_date'. This is due to the GROUP BY running before the SELECT statement and when I add MONTH(D.expected_date) it still needs DATEDIFF(mm,dbo.fn_firstofmonth(getdate()) to be added to the GROUP By in order for the query to function

Comment: I am assuming I could probably put the CASE statement in a sub query and do it that way

Comment: @TomMcDonough i have changed my query try it once again

Comment: Thanks, I am using sql server so I cannot use this function but even when I use Convert(Varchar(25),D.expected_date) it says the same error as before